# write json data in separate lines of csv

Tags: python, json

I have a csv file. I have a json file consisting of multiple lines. something like this:

```
{ "name":"John", "age": {"f": "1", "f2": "2"}, "city":"New York"}
{ "name":"John", "age": {"f3": "1", "f4": "2"}}
...
```

I want to visit each line one by one to see if it has `age` and `city`. In case it contains both of them (or one of them) I want to add these values (for example `"age": {"f": "1", "f2": "2"}`) to a row in csv file. For the next line, I want to do the same thing, but the result should be written in the next line of the csv file. In fact, the csv file should have 2 columns, one for `age`, one for `city`. I have written this code:

```
import json
import csv

result = []
for line in open('file.json', 'r'):
    result.append(json.loads(line))

for each in result:
    if 'age' in each:
        with open('document.csv', 'a+', newline='') as fd:
            fd.write(str(each["age"]))
            if 'city' in each:
                with open('document.csv', 'a') as fd:
                    fd.write(str(each["city"]))
```

The problem is that, it writes found results only in one row of the csv file, while I want the result of each line to be written in a new row of the csv file. by the way the data of the age is not written completely in one cell and it is broken in several cells. For example the 1st cell contains `{"f": "1"`, the 2nd row contains `"f2": "2"}`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be of help but -

```
m = [{ "name":"John", "age": {"f": "1", "f2": "2"}, "city":"New York"},{ "name":"John", "age": {"f3": "1", "f4": "2"}}]

pd.DataFrame(m)
```

```
    name    age                     city
0   John    {'f': '1', 'f2': '2'}   New York
1   John    {'f3': '1', 'f4': '2'}  NaN
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It only solved the second part, now the parts of "age" aren't broken. but how about applying and looking for some specific values like `age` or `city`?